# Squirrel Client Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, squirrel-sql

I am unable to create a stored procedure for an Oracle database using Squirrel Client.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Notify_Ins(
       ID  NUMBER,
       NAME CLOB,
       EMAILID VARCHAR2) as 
begin

  INSERT INTO test2 ("ID", "NAME", "EMAILID") 
  VALUES (ID, NAME,EMAILID);
END;
```

/

The above is my code and it gives me an error saying "INVALID SQL STATEMENT"
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You shouldn't name your input parameters like your column-names, but it should still work.
I tried it out without a problem with Toad. Never uses Squirrel Client.

Comment: Yea i just used that for example purpose. Anyways Noted!

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the Statement Separator to something else temporarily. In the menu item Session/Session Properties click on the SQL tab and change Statement Separator to GO

Comment: It doesn't hurt changing it this way even permanently. I usually set it to some obscure Unicode character (e.g. copy-n-paste from a web page) which is not likely to be a part of SQL